# onUploadComplete event of asyncFileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-ajax, asyncfileupload

how to display a btn after onUploadComplete event is executed? It's not coming now even I say btn.visible=true inside that event..

I read in one of the thread that this event happens asynchronously so we have to write javascript for it and call onClientUploadCompete.

But do anyone know how to do it withoiut writing javascript? please its urgent thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options - to execute client-side using JavaScript and AsyncFileUpload's `OnClientUploadError` and `OnClientUploadComplete`, or to handle the server-side `UploadedComplete` or `UploadedFileError` events fired by your AsyncFileUpload object.

If you choose client side, you can still include your `Button` as normal and include CSS for it to be `display: none`, which can be then altered in the JavaScript with something like the following:

```
$get(<%= AsyncFileUploaderInstanceName.ClientId %>).style.display = "block"
```

If you choose server side, you'll be able to refer to the `.Visible` property of whatever controls you like, and can alter them then.  However, you'll have to update whatever UpdatePanel the button would be sitting in for the button to be rendered on the page.

Comment: my issue is that When I am using UploadedComplete event, it's not working. I don't want to write a Javascript function now. Code is like :

Comment: protected void UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e) {if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile) {DataView dvAtt = dtAttachments.DefaultView;gvAttachments.DataSource = dvAtt; gvAttachments.DataBind(); panel_Popup_ModalPopupExtender.Show();

Comment: By not working, do you mean you're not actually seeing the event fire?  Are you sure the file is getting successfully uploaded?

Comment: the event is getting fired but when I write something like btnSave=true; inside that event it's not happening. I've used ModalPopUpExtender and inside that I've this asyncFileUpload control..I've already read somewhere that it happens asynchronously..what say?

Comment: Ian first off,thanx for your prompt response! Im actually doing more than just displaying a btn. Upon uploading a file..I want to display a gridview with the filename in it as a link..that's what I wrote inside that event..gridview1.databind and then Im displaying my modal Popup as all these are in it. So ur comments on this?

Comment: You're executing server-side code, yes.  However, in order to actually get the page to re-render server controls, you have to postback.  You can do this asynchronously by adding an UpdatePanel to the page which contains the controls you'll be altering in this event handler.  This is all assuming you want to rely on the Ajax Control Toolkit, of course.